# Application to the spectral theorem for commuting self-adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space.

If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are two commuting self-adjoint operators, il is well known that there exists a suitable measure space $(X,\mu)$,
two functions $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in L^\infty(\mu)$ and a unitary operator $U:E\longrightarrow L^2(\mu)$, such that each $A_k$ is unitarily equivalent to multiplication by $\varphi_k$, $k=1,2$. i.e.
$$UA_kU^*f=\varphi_kf,\;\forall f\in E,\,k=1,2.$$

I see the following paragraph in a paper

[image]

> Why 
>   $$\langle A_kf\;,\;f\rangle=\int_X\varphi_k|f|^2d\mu\;?$$
>   I don't understand why $A_kf=\phi_k f$?

Comment: What is your question? Sometimes you may want to write $A_k=\varphi_k$ because $A_k$ is unitarily equivalent to multiplication with $\varphi_k$ on a suitable $L^2$ space.

Comment: You can do that re-writing by changing coordinates in the domain and target via $U$.

Comment: @s.harp Please see my edit because I find in a paper that $$\langle A_kf\;,\;f\rangle=\langle \varphi_kf\;,\;f\rangle=\int_X\varphi_k|f|^2d\mu,$$

Comment: Because a unitary map does not change the scalar product (This is the definition of being unitary!)

Comment: It seems like an identification between $E$ and $L^2(\mu)$

Comment: You have a unitary from $E$ to $L^2(\mu)$. When you write $A_kf$ it is then most likely that $UA_k U^* f$ is meant, in other words $A_kf\equiv \varphi_k f$. Then $\langle \varphi_k f, f\rangle = \int_X (\varphi_k f)\overline f d\mu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you want to prove makes no sense, as $f\in L^2(\mu)$ and $A_k\in  L(E,E)$, so $A_kf$ is not defined.
From the spectral theorem, you get immediately
$$
\langle A_k (U^*f), U^*f\rangle_E = \int \phi_k |f|^2 \ d\mu.
$$

Comment: please see the paragraph from the paper, why  $A_kf=\phi_k f$?

Comment: please read my answer again, think again. $A_kf$ is meant to be $A_kU^*f$, after all they are talking about unitary equivalence, so some hidden identifikation $A_k \sim A_kU^*$ happens behind the scenes

Comment: Yes I understand very well your answer and it is clear for me. But my problem what is the wrong in the paper , because in the paper the autor write $A_kf=\phi_k f$ for all $f\in L^2$. The problem $A_k$ is not defined on $L^2$

Comment: please see your answer in the following link because you have used that $A_kf=\phi_kf$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541106/inequality-involving-two-normal-operators

Comment: @Student ........... no, I didnt.